# Clear All button on primeng multi-select

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, primeng, angular4-forms

Hi I am working on a Angular4 application and for UI I am using Primeng.

I have a multi-select element which behaves pretty much the same as it does over here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

The only thing I want different is on the drop-down, when "X" (close) button is clicked, I want it to clear all the selection instead of closing the drop-down itself.

Is there any way to achieve that in primeng ?

Help is appreciated !

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184003/clear-multi-select-with-a-button-angular-primeng-turbotable?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can manually trigger the checkbox in the left by jquery.

declare var jquery:any;

declare var $ :any;

$('.ui-chkbox-box.ui-widget.ui-corner-all.ui-state-default').trigger('click')

or you make the value of the p-multiselect equal to [].

Ex.

```
//html
 <p-multiSelect #multiselect> 
    <button type="button" (click)="functionToClear(multiselect)"</button> 
 </p-multiselect>

//ts
functionToClear(multiselect): void {
     multiselect.value = [];
}
```

Comment: This is for Angular 5, you can change the class selector to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, but you can clear all the selection by clicking the checkbox in the left corner twice.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't a supported functionality of the Multiselect PrimeNg component, if you really want it to do that, you would have to manually edit the component, `multiselect.js`, and modify the `close(event)` function to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use formGroup and try to clear value following way:

html:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [(ngModel)]="data"
                                        [data]="fetchedData" [settings]="customeSettings"
                                        formControlName="myControl">
                                    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

.ts:

```
this.form_name.controls.myControl.setValue("");
```

Comment: Simplest solution will be : 

this.form.get("formcontrolname").setValue([]);

Empty string will not work with this.

Answer (score 0):

normally the multi-select input in primeng is binded to a property that holds the selected members, usually an array.

you can use a reset button for example that when clicked, it will empty that propery/array and this will clear all the selected check boxes of the multi-select.

Answer (score 0):

Since PrimeNg version 13, you can use `[showClear]="true"` property to display an 'X' icon next to the control value.