# Clear multi-select with a button (angular primeng turbotable)

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

Is it possible to remotely clear a multi-select (or multiple multi-selects) with a button?  I'm using primeng multi-select with turbo table

I've seen this question a few times, but not with a selected answer.

Below is my multi-select:

```
<span *ngIf="col.field == 'Product'">
  <p-multiSelect [options]="getUniques(col.field)" 
                 (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')">
  </p-multiSelect>
</span>
```

Here is my button:

```
<p-button label="Clear All" 
          styleClass="ui-button-primary"
          (click)="onResetAll($event, dt)">
 </p-button>
```

Here is the method, where I try to reset values, but does not seem to reset:

```
onResetAll(event, dt) {
    dt.filter('', 'Product', 'contains');
}
```

Comment: What is dt here?

Comment: Show me stackblit please

Comment: @Danil Gudz  Dt is the name of the datatable.  #dt

Comment: one multiselect each row?

Comment: @phucnh I just have one multi-select per th column.  Will try to make a stackblit for it.  I primarily want to be able to reset at least one multi-select remote with a clear button click.

Comment: ok, wait for my answer

Comment: @user749798, that's clear what it means, but what is the code behind it? As I see this is an instance of a class with a filter value. Is p-multiSelect your own component or I can see a code if it is an opensource library. It seems like it has to have ngModel binding to pass data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below for multi multiselect

First set view children selector `#cmp`

```
<p-multiSelect #cmp [options]="cars" appendTo="body"
                 (onChange)="table.filter($event.value, 'brand', 'in')">
  </p-multiSelect>
```

In code behind declare setof components

```
@ViewChildren('cmp') components: QueryList<MultiSelect>;
```

And update your button click event

```
onResetAll(event, dt) {
    this.components['_results'].forEach(ds => {
      ds.value = null;
      ds.updateLabel();
    });
    dt.filter('', 'brand', 'contains');
  }
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbyf9j)

Comment: Perfect.  That worked great.  Was also easy to extend to all multi-selects.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution will be :

this.form.get("formcontrolname").setValue([]);

Answer (score 0):

To add to the solution above:-

```
onResetAll(event, dt) {
  this.components['_results'].forEach(ds => {
    ds.value = null;
    ds.updateLabel();
  });
}
```

If you are using chips then you will need to add:-

```
ds.cd.detectChanges();
```

As there is a refresh issue